# Am i using the correct loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby

i'm trying to input a string and output that same string with each letter one letter on in the alphabet. so "hi" would turn into "ij". this is the code i have so far and i'm not sure why it's not working. it just jumps straight to " this is not a letter in the alphabet" 
Here is my code:

```
def LetterChanges(str)

  count = 0

 x = str.split(//).each do |com|

   my_array = ('a'..'z').to_a

    if my_array.include? com
      if my_array[count] != com
       count += 1
      else
        puts my_array[count + 1]
      end

   else
      puts "this is not a letter of the alphabet"
   end

    end

end

LetterChanges("hello world")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you think about this method?

```
def LetterChanges(str)
  str.split(//).each { |i| i.next! if (('a'..'z').include? i) }.join()
end
```

Comment: haha oh wow i massively over complicated this didn't i. i did try something similar but the .next didn't work for me at all, i didn't realise using an exclamation mark changed it so much. could you explain why mine wasn't working?

Comment: @RebekahParsons Problem in the logic of this block: ` if my_array[count] != com
       count += 1
      else
        puts my_array[count + 1]
      end`